# Question ban for unanswered questions?

Tags: support, post-ban

I have only asked 2 questions before, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22457033/how-to-create-an-admin-shortcut-with-nsis) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22303640/java-form-file-menuitem-separator), but have answered a few with positive votes.

I just received the message "We are no longer accepting questions from this account.", indicating I am banned from asking questions.  But my two questions seem well-formed, have decent grammar, and are specific.  They both have 0 up-votes, but also 0 down-votes.

Is that enough to get my account banned?  And if so, is that really desirable in the community? I really *am* trying to be a good SO contributor.

Comment: And you did not delete any questions? These count too. Did you not read the link you were provided with?

Comment: You might be sharing IP address with question banned user, who tried to evade the ban by creating new accounts and thus got himself IP banned. Are you browsing from office?

Comment: As @ShadowWizard alludes to, there are some other ways a question ban can be applied. You do not have any deleted questions, so that is not an issue here. But what Shadow Wizard notes is almost certainly the problem, from what I can see. A Community Manager would have to go into more detail, probably privately.

Comment: @AndrewBarber so this means the original banned user can now register new account? In such case it won't be long before it's banned again.

Comment: Banned users are generally capable of registering new accounts, but continued bannings can result in more broad blocks and lower thresholds in the future. So, you are correct. This can also affect other, 'innocent' users at the same location. (which is why it's not a hard stop right away)

Comment: @juergend I don't think I deleted any, certainly not within the last several months, and I posted one of those questions recently.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I *am* browsing from the office.  I had never heard about this type of ban, interesting.  At least it may not be my fault.  I thought I did something I shouldn't have :-)

Comment: @codemonkey well, your mistake was working in a place where question banned people work too! ;)

Comment: You're not currently blocked, I'm looking into this.

Comment: I guess SO should work on banning the MAC ID of the system used, try to find the real identity of the user and get his twitter and FB accounts banned, his credit cards and bank accounts banned apart from banning the user id and IP because the user has zero upvotes on his questions.

Comment: @ShaktiPrakashSingh: Can't use the MAC address, it's not visible outside the relevant network segment.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You hit a very rare, but extremely confusing corner case. You had a bit of a rocky start when you started answering questions, which lowered the threshold for a question block a bit. With two zero scored questions *combined with* data about your answers, you reached the block. A single up vote on any of your questions would have lifted it - which appears to be what happened here.

I can't really go into any more detail than that without giving out the 'secret sauce' of how these work, but I can say that a series of heavily down-voted / zero scored answers can put you within the reach of a question block sooner than you'd reach it otherwise.

I don't think you'll hit it again, a couple more up voted posts are all that's needed to move you safely out of its reach.

Comment: Thank you!  I wasn't sure if the "rocky start" would affect anything, and now I know.  Though the timing was weird, I thought.  I had asked a question after my answers were being up-voted again.  Anyway, it's fixed now and thanks for looking into this. :-)

Comment: I am disturbed to hear that zero-scored questions and answers can get you into trouble.  I have a lot of those.  I guess I don't mind being ignored, but I didn't realize that being ignored can be so dangerous.

Comment: I agree @criticalfix.  I recently was question banned with no negative questions and 3 -1 negative answers (which I had revised but have not been upvoted).  Guess I'll have to wait for more upvotes on my answers...

Comment: I was given a question ban, is there something I can do? in order to fix this, I was gaining reputation and not getting any down voted questions, but now I am very confused.

Comment: @Alehandro Have you followed the link in the question ban notice that explains details about what you can do in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans)? Also, there's a Meta Post containing more detail on some of those subjects: [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583/7795130)

Comment: Yes but its basically telling me to go back, edit my questions and wait for upvotes, or someone to give me a plus mark, I am just confused because I was gaining reputation and everything seemed fine, especially with me getting points and up votes for certain questions the FAQ, explains "users who can't be bothered to form sentences
users who don't do the most basic kinds of research themselves
users who barely even explain what it is they are trying to do
An automatic filter is in place to ban questions and/or answers from IP addresses or accounts with a history of extremely poor posts

Comment: @Alehandro - Questions bans do not happen due one or two bad questions.  Question bans are a result of a pattern of questions that have not been well received.  You should improve your questions that have not yet been deleted.  If that does not result in those questions being upvoted, you have no choice but to wait 6 months, for your ability to ask another question.  *When you asked that question in 6 months make sure it's the best question you ever wrote.*