# What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?

Tags: support, faq, post-ban

Do not repost the question you were about to ask until you have

## [READ EVERYTHING IN THE ANSWER BELOW](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255584).

###### The answer below is the best information we have for people who are getting a notice that the system is no longer accepting questions or answers from their account. This is a tough situation. It's unlikely there's a quick fix. Resolving this is going to take work on the part of the person who owns the account. If that's you, and you want to resolve this, read the entire answer below.

## ⠀

While trying to ask a question, one could see:

> ## You can't post new questions right now
>
> ---
>
> Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from your account because most of your questions need improvement or are out of scope for this site. See the Help Center page [Why are questions no longer being accepted from my account?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) to learn more.
>
> Please **do not create a new account**. Instead, work on *improving your existing questions* by editing them to comply with [the site's guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and address any feedback you've received. You can also continue to contribute to the site in other ways, such as [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) other posts to improve them.

Likewise, for answers:

> Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions/answers from your account because most of your answers need improvement or do not sufficiently answer the question. See [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans) to learn more.

### The answer below covers the following points:

- Why am I getting this message?
- Are deleted posts taken into account too?
- Is a question/answer ban the same as a suspension?
- How do I avoid getting a question ban?
- How long do I have to wait before I can post again? What can I do to release the ban? How can I reactivate my account?
- Can I simply create a new account?
- I'll just ask on Super User or Server Fault, and they'll migrate my question to the correct site!

[Return to FAQ index](/q/251225)

Answer (score 140):

### Why am I getting this message?

As stated in the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), Stack Exchange is a network of *question and answer* sites, not discussion forums. This implies that all posts are expected to have value for later visitors, in addition to helping the asker. To enforce that, users that consistently post low-quality questions and answers are blocked. This includes posts that:

- are rude, abusive, or contain spam
- are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
- don't show research effort
- are unclear or not useful

  [image: An example of a poor quality question is titled "Any help please?" and contains just a link to a screenshot and the text "i'm stuck please help me out".]

An [automatic filter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56817/can-we-prevent-some-of-the-low-quality-questions-from-entering-our-system/60294#60294) is in place to ban questions and/or answers from IP addresses or accounts with a history of *extremely* poor posts.

To avoid users bypassing the filter, its internal rules are a secret, but it is partly based on downvotes cast by other members of the community. If the other members of the site consistently give your posts a low score, you should try to identify the reason(s) for this.

Once you have posted too many poorly-received questions or answers, you will be banned from posting more, and you will see the error message.

If a post was poorly-received (downvoted or closed), that will continue to count against your account **even if the post is deleted!**  Whenever possible, try to fix posts instead of deleting them.

Additionally, deletion itself counts against questions [less than 30 days old when deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91956/i-apparently-got-question-banned-for-deleting-some-of-my-old-zero-upvoted-quest/97720#97720) if others have invested time into answering or moderating (editing/reviewing) the question.

Finally, [deleted answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105116/sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-answers-from-this-account/105119#105119) always count toward an automatic ban on new accounts.

It's not a problem to have deleted posts, but if a large percentage of your posts are deleted (either by yourself or the community), then they are likely not suitable for the site. Posting them consumes time from users who read them, edit them, or [respond to them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74466/does-systematic-self-deleting-need-to-be-prevented/74471#74471). Therefore, [deleted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86982/should-i-avoid-deleting-my-questions/87029#87029) among many other factors, can cause the filter to affect you.

Be aware that an account might very well have many deleted posts, including [auto-deleted old low-score questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year).

### How can I find my deleted posts?

You can find all of your deleted questions with the '[Deleted questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/deleted-questions/current)' link at the bottom of the [questions tab in your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=questions). The same for deleted answers with the '[Deleted answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/deleted-answers/current)' link at the bottom of the [answers tab in your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=answers).

**I am unable to undelete my post after I have edited it...**

If you cannot undelete the post after editing it, then custom flag the post for a moderator to review, mentioning that you have substantially revised the question/answer. Moderators may decide to keep it deleted if the post still does not meet our quality guidelines.

### Is a question/answer ban the same as a suspension?

No. A suspension is a manual [temporary penalty](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) - during which a user cannot ask questions or post answers. All other privileges, including commenting and voting, are also revoked by temporarily setting your reputation to 1. Such suspension is publicly visible to other users.

A post ban is enforced automatically and only prevents posting questions or answers. It is invisible to others.

### How do I avoid getting a question ban?

[Read the pages in the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), particularly those [about asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and [the Stack Exchange model](https://stackoverflow.com/help/stackexchange). Investigate and search before you ask. Put effort into your questions.

Questions are expected to have value for later visitors, in addition to helping the asker. So, if many of your questions aren't answered, or are downvoted, closed, or deleted (by you or the community), then they didn't meet the expected quality. Be sure to understand why those things happen, and learn from them. Don't simply repost the same question again.

If you're not sure what qualifies as a "good question", there are some hints and tips available:

- [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) from the Stack Overflow Help Center
- [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) by Jon Skeet
- [How to Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/%7Eesr/faqs/smart-questions.html) by Eric S. Raymond
- [Getting Answers](https://www.mikeash.com/getting_answers.html) by Mike Ash

Questions that are cleanly formatted tend to be received better than ones that are unformatted, poorly formatted, over-use formatting, or use formatting types contrary to their intended use (e.g. using code formatting for emphasis). In particular, be sure to:

- Format code, errors, and data as **text** ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)).
- Do not use [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for text-based information (code, errors, data, etc.). Images can sometimes provide good supplementary information, but they should **not** be used for the purpose of including text-based information in your question.
- Indent your code and use one [indenting style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) consistently throughout your code. It doesn't really matter which style you choose (although, for some languages, some styles are more appropriate than others). *Pick a style* and *use it consistently* for all code in a single project/question.

Not doing any of the above greatly increases the likelihood that a question will be received poorly.

To learn about formatting:

- [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)
- [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)
- Try for yourself in [the formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

### How long do I have to wait before I can post again? What can I do to release the ban? How can I reactivate my account?

Automatic bans never expire or "time out". This means that you cannot simply wait for a certain amount of time. If you do not take action, you will never be allowed to post again. **The only way for the ban to be lifted is by contributing positively to the site**.

**Before you do anything else, *fix your existing posts!*** As noted above, downvotes cast by the rest of the community factor into the ban - so the single best thing you can do to get it lifted is to address any objections raised by others. Were your past questions unclear? Did they fail to show any effort on your part? Formatted or titled poorly? Too long or too short? **Then fix them!**

Note the emphasis on fixing. **Do not delete your posts.** As explained above, deleted questions (if less than 30 days old when deleted) do still count toward the question ban. Deleting your posts does not help to lift the ban. Only fixing does!

If you're unable to improve your existing questions, you'll get the chance to ask *one* new one six months after your last question. If that question is positively received, you **may** be able to continue asking questions; if not, then the ban will remain in effect, and you'll have to wait another six months to ask your next question.

Moderators *cannot* lift the ban, so don't bother to ask. The only way for the ban to be lifted is for you to start contributing positively to the site.

If you are banned from asking questions, contributing quality answers that get upvoted [might](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68884/why-i-cant-ask-questions/68885#68885) enable you to ask questions again. However, as the internals of the filter are secret, there is no way to know for sure.

### Can I simply create a new account (or delete my current account and recreate it)?

You could create a new account, but doing so **violates the rules for operating multiple accounts** - namely, [it allows you to do something you would otherwise be restricted from doing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57682/how-should-sockpuppets-be-handled-on-stack-exchange). Penalties for violating this restriction can vary:

- Your accounts may be deleted without warning.
- You *and others on your network* may find your questions are shown to fewer potential answerers or subjected to preemptive review when posted.
- You *and others on your network* may be prevented from asking questions entirely.
- If you opt to *[delete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account)* [your account](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account) and then later return to the site, your ability to ask questions may be [limited to one question per week](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234610/102937) until you have demonstrated an ability to ask useful questions.

Deleting and recreating a new account will hurt you, not help. Your question history is tracked at a lower level than your account, so a negative asking record will still affect a new account. Deleting your current profile will, however, make it close to impossible for you to improve your already existing questions and answer, as the system will not treat them as owned by the recreated profile for anything other than the post rate limits and question/answer bans. Thus, deleting and recreating your account will make it *harder* to get out of a question or answer ban.

### I'll just ask somewhere else on the SE network, and they'll migrate my question to the correct site!

Migrations are [not possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102293/block-migration-if-user-is-suspended-question-blocked-at-destination) if your account is banned from asking questions on the destination site. The question will simply be closed as off-topic, but not migrated.