# How do Zero-Score Questions Impact a Question Ban?

Tags: support, questions, post-ban, zero-voted-posts

I was recently question banned on SO and have been doing everything I can to reverse the ban.  I have no negative-score questions (although this question was at -2 before it was revised: [Scrolling through UITableView causes Exception and Crash only on iPhone 5C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25748671/scrolling-through-uitableview-causes-exception-and-crash-only-on-iphone-5c)), and three -1 answers (two of which have been revised, one of which cannot be revised since the question was deleted).  But I feel like I generally have a positive reputation.

I recently found this thread ([Question ban for unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251128/question-ban-for-unanswered-questions/251129)) where the accepted answer says asking Zero-score questions can cause a question ban.  Could this have been the reason why I was question banned?  I have earned 109 reputation over the past two days on positive answers and edits.  Can upvotes on my answers help lift my question ban?  What more is required of me?

I have read the help page on Question Bans but it is rather vague on how to lift the ban, or why I was banned in the first place:

> How can I get out of a question ban?
>
> The ban will be lifted automatically by the system when it determines that your positive contributions outweigh those questions which were poorly received.

And

> Stack Exchange has automatic filters in place to ban questions from accounts that have contributed many low-quality questions in the past. These filters help keep the quality of our sites high. The exact formula for the bans is not disclosed, but users are only banned if they have a significant number of heavily down-voted, zero-voted, or deleted posts. One or two bad posts will not cause you to be blocked from using the site.

Comment: Did you delete any downvoted questions over time?

Comment: I do not have any deleted questions.  The UITableView question linked in the original post was initially downvoted and deleted by the cleanup script.  I had it reopened, it was at -2, I added additional information, and the question was reset back to 0.  That was the only case where I ever had a question below 0.

Comment: The exact formula for the ban is a secret, no one knows except the SE folks. Yes, answers contribute towards lifting the question ban, all good posts count towards removing the ban.

Comment: Given your lack of a negative question history, I would bet real money that you do have some deleted questions.  I've never seen a question ban triggered on an account without any deleted questions and without any negatively score posts.  Your account is almost 18 months old but your first question is only a little more than 13 months old.   I'll be you have some old negatively scored questions in the 5 months between the 2 events you have forgotten about that are hurting you.

Comment: @psubsee2003 That was a pretty good guess.

Comment: @psubsee2003 you were right after all.  I had two negative questions that I completely forgot about.  Thank you and Bill for the tips.

Comment: @psubsee2003 That might not be always the case. I am in a similar situation as the OP - I have a 19 month old account and it was dormant for 15 months, and the only question that was deleted manually was on March 18. Although the first question I asked after creating the account was also deleted by the system because of being declared a 'dead' question.

Comment: @cst1992 if you are actually questions banned, you likely have deleted content you forgotten about, just as the OP did in this case.  It seems to take a lot more than what I see from your question history in your profile to trigger the ban.  Now if you are just getting a warning about a potential ban, that is a different situation (it is much easier to trigger the warning).

Comment: @psubsee2003 No warning; I'm banned: http://i.imgur.com/2oFsrKe.png

Comment: @JAL Are you still question banned?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Zero-score questions do not apply at all to the question ban, as far as we know.  There are a lot of accounts that have way more zero-score questions than you do that aren't banned, so any impact that they do have is negligible.

Just for reference, you do have two old, negatively-voted, deleted questions.

- [Search for Teams using ESPN API?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24958112/1288)
- [What is the quickest way to make a program crash in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16745688/1288)

You may or may not want to revise those and try to get them undeleted. They might be worth salvaging, but undeleting them might also backfire if they get even more downvotes.

You're not banned any longer, so you did manage to dig your way out. You'll still need to be careful, since you're now right above the banning threshold. Keep doing what you've been doing recently to get out of the ban and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, I had forgotten about those questions.  I may not want to fix the Java one, but the ESPN one I thought was reasonable.  It doesn't matter anyways, that API is closing in December.

Thanks for digging up those old questions.  Guess I just tried to push the downvoted-into-oblivion stuff out of my mind.

Comment: They do affect the various bans and rate limits in *one* way: they count toward various thresholds that trigger more strict checks. So if you have, say, 20 questions and all but 1 is 0, then a theoretical check that kicked in at 20 questions would apply when otherwise it might not - meaning the (potentially quite strict) checks would then hinge entirely on the score of the *one* question that wasn't sitting at 0. Lotta folks find themselves blocked because a few questions get downvoted and a whole lot more are just boring.

Comment: @Shog9 I guess I belong in that category. I have a few -1/-2 questions and an equal number of +1/+2 questions, but most of mine are at 0. I have two deleted questions as far as I can remember, and one of them was a 'dead' question(my first one on creating an account). http://stackoverflow.com/users/4037019/cst1992?tab=questions&sort=votes

Comment: You have four *visible* downvoted questions and a couple more deleted, @cst1992. Plus a bunch at 0. Work on the visible stuff.

Comment: Wouldn't the fact that zero score questions influence this ban disproportionately affect users of low traffic topics?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251129/5191731