# Why did asking a question with zero-score cause me to get question-banned without warning?

Tags: support, downvotes, post-ban, zero-voted-posts

I recently got hit with this infamous message when I was about to ask a question on Stack Overflow without warning:

> ### You have reached your question limit.
>
> Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) to learn more.

The [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) says that you get question-banned by having:

> ...a significant number of heavily down-voted, zero-voted, or deleted posts. One or two bad posts will not cause you to be blocked from using the site.

I have one deleted post that has a score of -13, which is why I deleted it. I have four down-voted questions. All of them have two or less down-votes, except for one question, which has -6.

I don't have "a significant number of heavily down-voted, zero-voted, or deleted posts." Zero-voted? I do have one zero-voted question.

The last question I asked was about Google App Engine loading abnormally slow. It has a score of zero at the time of writing.

Do zero-score questions get you banned from asking?. An answer to "[How do Zero-Score Questions Impact a Question Ban?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276347/how-do-zero-score-questions-impact-a-question-ban/276360#276360)" says that zero-score questions don't lead to question-bans. [One of Stack Overflow's Help Center articles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) said that zero-score questions do cause question-bans.

Since I have more down-voted questions than up-voted ones, a zero-score question will actually improve my average. Why'd I get banned?

Was I banned from just that question, or was it a coincidence, and I got banned for something else?

And why'd I get question-banned without warning? It just banned me one day.

Comment: Deleted posts count against you still. From your own post, it looks like you have 5 negatively scoring questions.

Comment: you have 7 questions, with only 2 of them being positively voted... i'd consider that a significant number of heavily downvoted questions. Even your 2 upvoted questions are also downvoted several times (though I don't know if that affects the ban)

Comment: I've always "significant number" as "significant %". Obviously someone with 10 DVed questions, but 1000 of UVed ones, should not be banned. But someone with 10 DVed questions ONLY..... different

Comment: You have a net -11 votes from all your questions.  Include the deleted one and that's -24.  Surprised you got that far.

Comment: I'm not sure you're really *getting* SO. You're review- and now post-banned and your meta "contributions* are more-or-less uniformly unpopular. It might be wise to spend a little more time lurking.

Comment: A zero score answer is not considered a good question so it still can count against you.

Comment: @Andy: I found the original trace of this question (comments on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/278941/). "Without warning" are the operative words. False duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A question with 0 votes is not considered a good question and the post ban algorithm is checked when you are asking a question which means that your last question was enough to push you over the bubble.

Answer (score 43):

Of your 10 questions, 50% are downvoted, 30% are deleted, 20% score 0 and 20% score > 0.

If you were gonna place a wager on the outcome of your *next* question, where would you put your money?

Comment: ["outlook not so good"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1696/165773)

Comment: Nitpicking, but don't you mean 60% downvoted? (5 undeleted and the deleted -13 one)

Comment: It *was* 50% when I wrote this...

Comment: Oh, maybe I'm reading it wrong then. 50% downvoted + 20% score 0 + 20% score > 0 should be 100% right?

Comment: The percentages overlap.

Comment: Right, but 50% + 20% + 20% = 90%. I mean counting without the deleted questions that I assume you are referring to when you say there is overlap. If I understand you correctly, you are saying that 50% scored negatively, 20% scored at 0, and 20% scored above zero. Since that theoretically covers all possibilities, shouldn't there be one more question included to account for the other 10%? Sorry to bother you about something so trivial, but I figured I already started the conversation, might as well finish it. :)

Comment: @Anonymous the percentages measure different things. Each percentage is separate, not part of an equation. Like 30% of the people in the room have blue eyes and 80% of the people in the room are taller than four feet.