# Should I delete my off-topic question?

Tags: support, closed-questions, deletion

My question appears to be off-topic. I want to delete it to avoid directing people toward a cul de sac question. However, we are warned not to delete questions... How should I proceed?

Comment: You are warned not to delete questions to try and get out of a question ban as they'll keep counting towards the question ban anyway, you are encouraged to delete questions which are not ever going to be valuable on Stack Overflow. The button is there for a reason.

Comment: I deleted it before [Meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect) could kick in. As long as it's zero score, it shouldn't hurt you

Comment: @Machavity I'm not sure about that. Zero-score is not considered "positively received". See [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) about "If that question is positively received, you may be able to continue asking questions" and [Why did asking a question with zero-score cause me to get question-banned without warning?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/299315)

Comment: @user1771398 I have not seen your question, but is there a possibility to edit the question to make it on topic?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392678

Comment: @Scratte True, but a deleted negative score is worse than a deleted zero score (in theory). Either way, the question was off-topic and letting Meta downvote it would serve no real purpose

Comment: I wish I can add this answer to my question : I just edited the off-topic question with the reference toward the same question at the right place - will you vote to reopen this question in this purpose ? I feel it will help the community.

Comment: @oleg I agree that the question is general, but I disagree that there are no answers to this question (see proposed answer above)

Comment: @user1771398 - sorry, but I am not sure I understand what are you talking about - did you intend to ping someone else?

Comment: @oleg I made a confusion between you editing and somebody else, anonymous, that closed the question - sorry for the confusion

Comment: @ samcarter : no way, it was really the wrong place for the question

Comment: @user1771398 NP. They are not anonymous, this is a peer review process, 5 people closed the question for lacking details. Plus there are at least 2 reopen votes currently.