# Should zero score questions impact post bans?

Tags: discussion, post-ban, zero-voted-posts

So I checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) and sure enough it says that " if [you] have a significant number of heavily down-voted, zero-voted, or deleted posts." you will get a question ban. I just received my first one :( I am not here to request to get unbanned. It was my fault and I don't blame anyone else.

Should they really affect the ban? Also how bad would it be to stop counting 0 vote posts in your score average?

Comment: Why *shouldn't* they be incorporated?  You're the one proposing a change.  Justify why you think the change would be beneficial.

Comment: [Relevant data](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276347/how-do-zero-score-questions-impact-a-question-ban?rq=1#comment115674_276360)

Comment: So.... Would you hire a "meh" candidate if he NEVER wowed you? There is as point where if you cannot get ONE upvote..... Something needs to change in regards to the quality of your Qs.... So yes it is appropriate. The ban looks at your average score. Someone with one +8 question and no bad ones is better than someone with one +8 and seventen 0s,no?

Comment: I understand I need to improve my questions.  But the 2nd I think would be better. They are more active and sometimes people just don't upvote. I often forget to upvote good questions. I am not saying that is the reason I got banned is people forgot to upvote. But it _does_ happen that people forget to upvote

Comment: Do you mind linking to something worth an upvote of yours that didn't get one? Anyway.... Never getting an upvote is pretty much a good sign your questions are neutral at best. Mostly neutral with a couple of bad ones? I wouldn't bet on your next questoon getting a +5 with that track record... And neither does the system

Comment: The point here is ***significant number***...if you are asking **a lot** of questions and not getting upvotes...then there's clearly something wrong with your questions. Community involvement is nice...but it has to be **positive** involvement.

Comment: Does anyone read what I said? I already said that @Paulie_D. I get it. I asked many questions that were meh

Comment: I don't think I will. @Patrice However I am pretty stuck right now. I can barely ever answer questions here. So I  guess I will get my unban to probation in about 6 months

Comment: You're not reading what I said...if your questions aren't getting votes, it's likely that they are **poor questions**.

Comment: IMHO a 100 0 score questions and nothing else is not a good contribution.  It's not really bad but it is not good and good is what we are looking for.

Comment: @ChristopherPeart so.... You don't WANT to link good content? Weird. If it truly is good content you believe is worth upvoting (assuming you are right and it is worth theupvotes), showing it to meta is a good way to get more eyeballs and the score it deserves. Anyway answers don't do much for a Q ban... Maybe after the warning you got last time, posting a question where a google search of the error got a duplicate wasn't the right thing to do...

Comment: My 0 vote questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41572446/scaleing-apps-in-processing-and-keep-the-aspect-ratio-the-same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36521403/prevent-refreshing-when-submitting-on-html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37925327/when-trying-to-remove-an-item-from-array-errors Judge them how you will

Comment: And my positive questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35530221/using-processing-and-getting-an-unexpected-token-on-my-array-hackathon http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36509592/using-inputs-in-html-to-run-functions and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39712053/give-priority-to-the-y-value-of-a-vector

Comment: So the Khan academy code (last question) I stopped scrolling through your ENTIRE codebase whenI saw you needed an MCVE. Maybe work on putting only what's needed of code to trigger the error, not the full project?

Comment: [That last zero-score question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37925327/when-trying-to-remove-an-item-from-array-errors) doesn't even have a language tag! No wonder it didn't get many votes!

Comment: @CodyGray the language is processing a version of JS

Comment: Your first zero score question has NO code, two questions at once, and is lacking so much info it is virtually impossible to do more than guess at a solution. Are those really what you consider worth upvoting? Because these..  Linked on meta, will only attract more downvotes:/. That's why I said "if you are right and the Qs are worth upvotes".

Comment: @Patrice I never said that happened to me. In fact I was very specific to make sure I didn't

Comment: And TBH if they deserve downvotes give them

Comment: @ChristopherPeart well considering that is what I requested... I assumed that was your point of view on them.   And btw back to the khan academy code: you went the opposite way. Now I don't even know what is the array..... We need a minimal example that will reproduce the error... Not just the line that triggers it(apologies if my phrasjng was unclear before) And I try to not do the meta effect downwards... Unless it truly is a horrendous Q.

Comment: I personally don't particiapte much in Meta Effect up/down voting (but still vote to close), but your [last](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41754441) -6 question is really bad - basic search https://www.bing.com/search?q=java%20array%20max%20size immediately gives you an answer, no real MCVE, no exact error - looks like you really went all the way to get question ban :(

Comment: @CodyGray "processing" just bad tag... I tried to come up with better name - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286694/rename-processing-to-processing-language-or-similar, but there were not much consensus on what that name should be.

Comment: Instead of "If they deserve downvotes give them", why don't you take the constructive criticism you've gathered here and apply them to your posts so that they *don't* warrant downvotes and could even possibly warrant upvotes?

Comment: @TinyGiant I will once I have time to.

Comment: I edited a few of my questions to include better code examples

Comment: I edited all of my 3 0 vote questions to have better code and code examples and the most important all of them have a MPVE.

Comment: I was inspecting my insane rep drop from yesterday I noticed that 10 of it was from user removed.... On the day that I lost 27 rep 10 was from that. Thanks SO hit a man while he is down

Comment: @ChristopherPeart that is just an automated process that removed the 10. A user that upvoted one answer (or 2 questions) requested to get his account deleted. That invalidated his votes.

Comment: @Patrice I understand that

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, zero-voted questions should not be counted as positive contributions because they are not positive contributions to the site.

Votes indicate usefulness and quality of the question. A score of zero means no one found it useful and its quality is so-so. Such questions take away time that other people can spend answering more useful questions and increase noise in search results, decreasing the usefulness of Stack Overflow for everyone.

Stack Overflow already gets plenty of such questions already and there is no need to encourage more.

Comment: Your point stands, but besides meaning "no one found it useful and its quality is so-so", it can also mean that just as many people found it useful and found it not useful (i.e., in a net 0 situation).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan good point. I personally think that no one actually downvotes questions for "not useful" - if one found question via search they start with "likely not what I'm looking for" bias so they upvote perfect match, but not vote on the rest.

Comment: I donwnvote anything I feel is not useful. Most users arriving from google don't have accounts, so can't vote at all.

Comment: @TinyGiant I feel those of us that actually downvotes posts that aren't useful are a sufficiently small number of users that saying, "no one actually downvotes posts for being not useful" is a close enough approximation to the truth.  When 0.001% of users actually downvote posts they think aren't useful it might as well be no users.

Comment: @Servy There are plenty of downvotes cast every day. I don't think that saying "no one actually downvotes posts for being not useful" without any sort of supporting evidence is useful.

Comment: is undeleting zero voting questions good idea?

Comment: @VasylKolomiets from the site's point of view - mostly no, especially without edits... From q-ban side - indeed - if you can improve them or if they have answers (covered in https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th).